# Android Camera X ViewPort

Tags: android, camera

I use this code for Camera X binding. When I run app for the first time everything works fine. But when I close app and start it again I get "ViewPort is NULL". Why viewPort is NULL I do not understand. What is wrong with my code?

```
@OptIn(markerClass = androidx.camera.lifecycle.ExperimentalUseCaseGroupLifecycle.class)
private void bindAllCameraUseCases() {
    if (cameraProvider != null) {
        // As required by CameraX API, unbinds all use cases before trying to re-bind any of them.
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        createPreviewUseCase();
        createImageCaptureUseCase();
        createAnalysisUseCase();

        if (previewUseCase != null && analysisUseCase != null && imageCaptureUseCase != null) {
            ViewPort viewPort = ((PreviewView)findViewById(R.id.preview_view)).getViewPort();
            if (viewPort != null) {
                @OptIn(markerClass = androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalUseCaseGroup.class)
                UseCaseGroup useCaseGroup = new UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                        .addUseCase(previewUseCase)
                        .addUseCase(analysisUseCase)
                        .addUseCase(imageCaptureUseCase)
                        .setViewPort(viewPort)
                        .build();

                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(/* lifecycleOwner= */ this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup);
                LiveData<Integer> torchStateObserver = camera.getCameraInfo().getTorchState();
                torchStateObserver.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(Integer state) {
                        torchState = state;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "VIEWPORT is NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By closing app, do you mean that you kill the app and re-start or just put into background and bring to foreground?

Comment: I mean restart app. If I put app into background and resume it everything is ok again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `PreviewView` is not attached to the window. You can find this information in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getViewPort()) for `getViewPort()`:

> null if the view is not currently **attached** or the view's width/height is zero.

Solution is to listen when `PreviewView` is attached, for example like this:

```
if (!previewView.isAttachedToWindow) {
    previewView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(
        object : OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(view: View?) {
                bindCameraToLifecycle(cameraProvider)
                (view as PreviewView).removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this)
            }

            override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    )
} else {
    bindCameraToLifecycle(cameraProvider)
}
```

Where `bindCameraToLifecycle()` looks like this:

```
fun bindCameraToLifecycle(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
    uiHandler.post {
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            lifecycleOwner,
            CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA,
            UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                .setViewPort(previewView.viewPort!!)
                .addUseCase(preview)
                .addUseCase(imageAnalyzer)
                .build()
        )
    }
}
```